# Validating textarea with 2 conditions Contact Form 7

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I'd like to execute 2 tests on a textarea within a CF7 form.

First: the textarea does not contain an url

Second: the same textarea does not contain email address

I tried this code:

```
function custom_textarea_validation_filter($result, $tag) {
$type = $tag['type'];
$name = $tag['name'];
if($name == 'yourmessage') {
$value = $_POST[$name];
if(preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$value)||preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$#",$value)){ 

    $result->invalidate( $tag, "Merci de ne pas inclure de liens, url, ou adresse email !" );
                }
}
return $result;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_textarea','custom_textarea_validation_filter', 10, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_textarea*', 'custom_textarea_validation_filter', 10, 2);
```

yourmessage is the textarea I want to test

But it does not work well: url are detected but not email adress...
I can't create two funtions because if the first evaluation is ok, the second is useless.

Thanks for any advices.
Gromit

Comment: Try using a single pattern combining the 2 patterns using an alternation `|`

Comment: I tried this:   $Match_all = "/(/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i|#^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$#)/";
if(preg_match($Match_all,$value)){     but without sucess. Many difficulties with regexp ...

Comment: It could be something like this https://regex101.com/r/PTudxX/1 `$Match_all = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]|^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$/"; if(preg_match($Match_all,$value)){`

Comment: Another thanks for your help!  it seems this (below) regexp match "all" (perhaps most of) cases: email beginning the line, email with other strings around, url beginning a line or around other strings:

Comment: \b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]|^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$|[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$

Comment: So with 3 regexp and 2 alternative symbols

Comment: No there is 1 alternation `|`

Comment: \b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]|^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$|[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}$

Comment: The first pattern for url, then alternation, then the second pattern for a email address beginning a line, then alternation, and to finish, a pattern for email address surrounded by other strings. Do I misunderstand something ? I used the website that you advised me. Thanks a lot for your patience !

Comment: You are right. One alternation and this regexp works wherever the 2 patterns are included: \b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]|[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}   with no $ at end which causes issue when email adress is followed by another string.

Comment: Yes, if you use the anchors `^` and `$` you will assert the start and the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone interested in implementing this kind of filter (url and email address in textarea in a Contact Form7 form - wordpress):

```
function custom_textarea_validation_filter($result, $tag) {  
$type = $tag['type'];
$name = $tag['name'];
if($name == 'yourmessage') {
$value = $_POST[$name];
$Match_all = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]|[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,8}/";
if(preg_match($Match_all,$value)){

    $result->invalidate( $tag, "Merci de ne pas inclure de liens, url, ou adresse email !" );
                }
}
return $result;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_textarea','custom_textarea_validation_filter', 10, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_textarea*', 'custom_textarea_validation_filter', 10, 2);
```

Thanks to "The fourth bird" for having helped me !

Gromit